# How to Shift Comma Inside Closing Quotes in Index

Tags: indexing, makeindex, comma-separated-list, quotation, idxlayout

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\newpage A sentence\index{\textbf{Comma Shift}@!Comma shift@\textcolor{red}{``How to move comma inside closing quotes''}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

QUESTION: For indices involving quotations, such as the one displayed, how may I shift the comma so that it appears immediately prior to the closing quotes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `csquotes` for this. The colour makes things slightly awkward, but this can be worked around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\def\fmtpage{\normalcolor\textbf}
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|fmtpage}}

\begin{document}
A sentence\index{\textbf{Comma Shift}@!Comma
shift@\color{red}\textquote{How to move comma inside closing quotes}}

Another sentence\index{\textbf{Comma Shift}@!Comma
shift@\textcolor{red}{\enquote{How to leave comma outside closing quotes}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer.